# Deploy FirefoxOS packed app on the device

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-os

Ok, i have a packed app build for FF OS ( zip archive ). It's installing without any problems on the emulator. Is there any way i can deploy this app to the real device? ( I have Keon ) I didn't found "push to device" options in emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't mentioned if you've installed drivers for Keon, it's a necessary step if you're on Windows or Linux.

If that's the case just follow this guide: [Pushing Firefox OS Apps to the Geeksphone](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2013/05/pushing-firefox-os-apps-to-the-geeksphone/)

Comment: Ye.. It's seems that I forgot to do some additional preparations ( i'm on MAC OS ) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox_OS/Debugging/Connecting_a_Firefox_OS_device_to_the_desktop

Comment: On Linux you do NOT need to install any drivers. As long as adb is installed you can fire up firefox os simulator or app manager and use them to push your app to the device

Answer (score 0):

WebIDE in Latest Firefox Browsers has made it still easier. Have a look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/WebIDE) .

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find any info about debugging on actual device. I know I can use simulator to debug an app, but this is not good enough for me.

Comment: Click [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Debugging/Connecting_a_Firefox_OS_device_to_the_desktop) You have the entire documentation regarding debugging app on real device!let me know if u face any problem.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Debugging/Setting_up  Note: This no longer works on Firefox OS devices as of January 10, 2013. As of this date device builds of Firefox OS have debugging disabled. There will eventually be a way to build your own build with it re-enabled, but this doesn't exist yet. This document will be updated once that happens. In addition, the preference for turning off out-of-process support has been removed. For now, you'll need to do your debugging in the Firefox OS Simulator.

Comment: There is a link to WebIDE on that page. Anyways click [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/WebIDE) directly!you will get it directly.